# Failed to find ID. Ensure that you have an ID property on your model error in Sitecore Experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

I have upgraded my Sitecore instance instance from `Sitecore 8.2` to `Sitecore 9.3`

I am getting below errors in experience editor mode but in normal mode component is not showing because we added error handling pipelines for view and controller rendering.

[image]

Error in Text

```
Inner Exception Failed to find ID. Ensure that you have an ID property on your model.
 at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.EditFrame[T](T model, String title, TextWriter output, Expression`1[] fields) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\GlassHtml.cs:line 199

    at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView`1.BeginEditFrame[T](T model, String title, Expression`1[] fields) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Web\Mvc\GlassView.cs:line 296 
    at ASP._Page_Areas_Clinical_Views_Listing_L05B_ListingProvidersWithTabs_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\local-cm.atriumhealth.org\Areas\Clinical\Views\Listing\L05B-ListingProvidersWithTabs.cshtml:line 20 
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
    at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) 
    at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
```

My Code is

```
 public class TestViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the id
        /// </summary>
        [SitecoreId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have face same problem in my project, after some investigation I found that Glass Mapper properties needs to be virtual, so try below code and let me know if it's works for you or not.

```
 public class TestViewModel
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the id
       /// </summary>
       [SitecoreId]
       public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

      }
```